# Chrome not firing onchange event when entering a space on HTML input field with type email

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onchange

I was wondering if anyone can reproduce the following issue.

This was tested in Chrome 38.0.2125.101 beta-m

When I enter a **space** in a regular `<input type="text">` field, the onchange event is fired.
With an `<input type="email">` though, the onchange event does not fire.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L8j2hmme/

Any ideas?

Comment: this bug still exists in chrome 48.0.2564.109 m

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me but action is fired with delay and when multiple spaces are typed.Also whitespace is not valid character

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" />


function _x(elem){
   return document.getElementById(elem);
}

var x = _x("email");

x.onchange = function(){
 console.log(1);
}
```

Comment: Spaces still don't fire the onchange event using the code you provided. (Tested In Chrome 38).

Comment: test the above code again. When you punch spacebar in input[type="email"] wait for some time it logs 1 to console.Aslo remember to punch multiple times back and forth.